# Will this php code (field_view_field) work if i put this inside body field of a node with php filter?

Tags: nodes, entities

Will this work if i put this inside body field of a node with php filter?

```
<?php echo "<h4>How are doing? Rate this site</h4>" ?>
<?php print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_fivestar_rating')); ?>
```

I tried in there but its displays an error.

Notice: Undefined variable: node in eval() (line 2 of C:\ssatempsite\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7562 of C:\ssatempsite\includes\common.inc).

Comment: `$node` is not defined. Check this [API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7) `The entity containing the field to display. Must at least contain the id key and the field data to display.`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code.

```
  $node = node_load(1);
  print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_fivestar_rating'));
```